# Accessing a property coming from manytomany field

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

This is my models.py:

```
class Role(models.Model):
    type= models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Profile(models.Model):
    role = models.ManyToManyField(Role, blank=True)

    def is_composer(self):
        return self.role['Composer']
```

This is my view.py:

```
from .models import Profile, Role
def profiles_filtered(request, type):
    model = Profile
    if type == 'composers':
        queryset = Profile.objects.filter(is_composer = True)
```

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('profiles/<str:type>/', views.profiles_filtered, name="profiles"),
]
```

And my template:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'profiles' 'composers' %}"> Composers</a></li>
```

When I click on the link, I get to `/profiles/composers/`, which should list all the profiles containing the role 'Composer'.  I get a

```
FieldError at /profiles/composers/
Cannot resolve keyword 'is_composer' into field.
```

The `Role` type contains many roles, one of which is 'Composer'. How can I list only the profiles which contain a 'Composer' role?

**addendum**

If I use

```
    if type == 'composers':
        queryset = Profile.objects.filter(role == 'Composer')
```

I get

```
NameError at /profiles/composers/
name 'role' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking for the filter where `role` is equals `Composer` then:

```
if type == 'composers':
    queryset = Profile.objects.filter(role__type__contains="Composer")
```

`type` is property of `role` object so, `role__type` is equivalent to *role's type* and `__contains` is django filter process, lets say.